# Move div horizontally when scroll vertically ( jquery or CSS3)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I want to move a div from left to right, when page is scroll down or up.
When page scroll down it should move right and when page is scroll up it should move left.

Comment: I have a div <div style="margin-left:15px;"> I want to increase margin-left from 15px to 400px; with scroll bar, as scroll down it should increase and as scroll up it should decrease.

Comment: @bigtechideas : Post some code you tried. Better create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See here a little example, a red box will scroll horizontally according to the percentage of the page you scrolled vertically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height();

        scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

        $horizontal.css({
            'left': position
        });
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PvVdq/