# Move div horizontally by vertical scroll in a range

Tags: jquery, css

Question is very similar to [Move div horizontally when scroll vertically ( jquery or CSS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333085/move-div-horizontally-when-scroll-vertically-jquery-or-css3)

I have a specific spot in a long page that when the user has scrolled to it, I want to move a div from off the page (right) across the screen to off the page left.

In the link above they use document height which I don't think helps me.

I've got as far as figuring out when to trigger the move with:

```
if ((win_height+scroll_top) > start_trigger)
{
    // Move calc
}
```

I'd like the div to travel the distance of the screen by the time they've scrolled the view port height.

The starting point of the div is `right: -464px`.

There's a relationship between the window width (distance to go) and window height (time to move in) but I can't figure out how to set the start position of the div when `start_trigger` is reached.

`start_trigger` is say 5000px. It changes a bit with screen width.

Here's a link: http://tikitour.haricot.co/ usually the "scene" beneath the "choose your character" slider is hidden until you go through it so the height changes.

Scroll until you see the fire truck. Hope that helps.

Another example of what I'm trying to achieve is the "thief" on Ben the bodyguard: http://benthebodyguard.com/index.php - not been able to dissect that yet.

Comment: you should include HTML and CSS and make a short example so we can help you. from just 'stories' we can't help

Comment: "Stories" to you, problem description to others. I've added a link, hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ok. check here. made a simple example

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/5gj9c9h5/1/)**

you need to calculate the element `offset().top` ( distance to top of the document ) and compare it to `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();`

let me know if it helps

JQ code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".moving").each(function() {
        a = $(this).offset().top 
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).animate({
            'right':'100%',
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer any of the points in my question. I've said I know _when_ to start the move (with code example). Using animate to move it doesn't move it in sync with the vertical scroll or get it done in the range of window height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this manually, but I know that exist jQuery plugin with scroll effects though - **scrollmagic**
http://scrollmagic.io/